# Now that React Native has auto-linking, do we still need to use `react-native unlink` to unlink?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, autolink

Now that React Native includes auto-linking, we no longer have to use `react-native link`. If we want to remove a library, we do `npm uninstall <lib>`, but do we still have to do `react-native unlink <lib>` as before, or how do we remove the code added to files like `build.gradle`?

**UPDATE**

Based on one of the responses, I tried running `npm uninstall <lib>; cd android; gradlew cleanBuildCache;`, but there are still many references to the `<lib>` in the `android/build` folder. This is causing problems because when I try to install another library, it's throwing conflict errors with the leftover references to `<lib>`.

Does anyone know what exactly `gradelw cleanBuildCache` does, and if there's any other command that will completely undo everything that happened from running `npm install <lib>`?

Comment: Yes it's quite good that react native includes auto-linking. But some of the libraries you will come to use still won't support auto-linking. So in that case you will have to link them manually.

 For eg., In android you will have to add the dependency in gradle and settings.gradle file. 
Some of the libraries i came across were `react-native-image-picker` and `react-native-firebase`.

Comment: Yep, I still make sure to follow the instructions carefully. What I was wondering though is when you remove a library that WAS auto-linked, should you run `react-native unlink <lib>`.

Comment: Yes, you should. As i told you there is an issue with linking the libraries same happens with unlinking them. Also you can do them manually if needed.

Comment: if you modify native files you better just go `android/app` and delete `build` folder. then rebuild project. adding new lib may need to change native files so try this.

Comment: @Ajeett Re "do them manually" do you mean go through build files and remove references to the modules manually?

Comment: @Amas Thanks, I'll do this.

Comment: @gkeenley lemme know the results

Comment: @Amas I've done this once before, removing all references to the module from everywhere in the project, and it did work. For this time though, I found it worked fine if I just did `npm uninstall`, deleted the android/app/build folder (I'm just building for Android right now), and rebuilt with react-native run-android.

Answer (score 1):

just clean your gradle and  rebuild your project

```
cd android 
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

then rebuild project again

if using Android studio then just Invalidate Caches

Comment: Hi Aurangzaid, thanks for getting me started, this didn't quire resolve it though. See updated question.